# Ionic iOS Build and Run

Tags: ios, build, ionic-framework

I'm new in ionic app development. I've completed the setting for android in windows and it is running fine in browser and android emulator also.
But I unable to build and Run the app for iOS in windows.
Is it possible to build and Run it in windows for iOS app or I need OS X ?

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately to build your app for iOS you'd require Xcode, which is not available on windows, therefore you need OSX if you want to develop for iOS too.

[See Ionic official docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/testing.html)

Comment: Well the makes me a little bit upset - because Ionic promotes "build once deploy everywhere" which isn't the case. It should be build once - install on multiple systems - deploy everywhere slowly...

Answer (score 0):

must be use Xcode on MAC you can use vmware :

> [Install OS X El Capitan 10.11 Retail on VMware on Windows PC and install Xcode From mac store](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wodqGvug6e0)

Answer (score 0):

You must need xcode to run build on ios mobile, and XCode only support on mac os.

So you can use virtual box to make virtual mac os into your windows system.

I hope you understand.